# IBrokers R API and same day intraday prices

Tags: interactive-brokers, ibrokers

I think this is be an IB API more than the IBrokers R package.
I am using `reqHistoricalData` to get 30 minutes intraday historical data. The market is open and I am not getting the same day's data. I only get yesterday's data.

Is it possible to get the same day intraday bar data?
here is the code I am using, it only gives data for the previous day, not same day.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(IBrokers)
tws = twsConnect()
contract <- twsEquity('VOD','SMART')
VOD_intraday = IBrokers::reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract = contract, endDateTime = "20210408 13:24:28", barSize = "1 min", duration = "1 D")
VOD_intraday %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column(var = "time") %>% arrange(desc(time)) %>% head()
```

It's 13:27 GMT on 2021-04-08 and London is open. And here is the response - it only gives data from 2020-04-07:

```r
> contract <- twsEquity('VOD','SMART')
> VOD_intraday = IBrokers::reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract = contract, endDateTime = "20210408 13:24:28", barSize = "1 min", duration = "1 D")
waiting for TWS reply on VOD .... done.
> VOD_intraday %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column(var = "time") %>% arrange(desc(time)) %>% head()
                 time VOD.Open VOD.High VOD.Low VOD.Close VOD.Volume VOD.WAP VOD.hasGaps VOD.Count
1 2021-04-07 20:59:00    18.96    18.98   18.95     18.98       1131  18.958           0       265
2 2021-04-07 20:58:00    18.96    18.96   18.95     18.96         90  18.957           0        42
3 2021-04-07 20:57:00    18.96    18.97   18.95     18.95        258  18.960           0        72
4 2021-04-07 20:56:00    18.96    18.96   18.95     18.95        124  18.959           0        58
5 2021-04-07 20:55:00    18.96    18.96   18.95     18.96         56  18.958           0        34
6 2021-04-07 20:54:00    18.95    18.96   18.95     18.95         26  18.951           0        12
```

Instead of VOD, you can use SPY, MSFT or any US security while the US market is open.

Edit: It turns out you need realtime subscription to get same day data. The answer below works.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting intraday historical data for today at 1 min intervals.  Can you share the parameters you passed to the reqHistoricalData call?

Comment: Hi @SNovogoratz: I edited the response. Could you test it to see if you get the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to specify the ending time, or leave it blank to get the most recent data available.

Try this:

```
 VOD_intraday = IBrokers::reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract = contract, endTime = "", barSize = "1 min", duration = "1 D")
```

Here's the execution when I run it:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(IBrokers)
IBrokers version 0.9-10.  Implementing API Version 9.64

IBrokers comes with NO WARRANTY.  Not intended for production use!


See ?IBrokers for details.
> tws = twsConnect()
> contract <- twsEquity('SPY','SMART')
> VOD_intraday = IBrokers::reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract = contract,     endDateTime = "", barSize = "1 min", duration = "1 D")
waiting for TWS reply on SPY ........... done.
> head(VOD_intraday)
                    SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.WAP  SPY.hasGaps SPY.Count
2021-04-08 07:30:00   407.93   407.98  407.68    407.80       5042 407.846           0      1709
2021-04-08 07:31:00   407.81   408.00  407.74    407.98       1615 407.844           0      1065
2021-04-08 07:32:00   407.99   408.05  407.81    407.90       2451 407.932           0      1560
2021-04-08 07:33:00   407.89   407.98  407.88    407.95       2353 407.932           0      1300
2021-04-08 07:34:00   407.95   407.97  407.81    407.81       1708 407.907           0      1012
2021-04-08 07:35:00   407.82   407.86  407.61    407.67       2729 407.726           0      1458
```

And for symbol VOD:

```
> contract <- twsEquity('VOD','SMART')
> VOD_intraday = IBrokers::reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract = contract, endDateTime = "", barSize = "1 min", duration = "1 D")
waiting for TWS reply on VOD .... done.
> head(VOD_intraday)
                    VOD.Open VOD.High VOD.Low VOD.Close VOD.Volume VOD.WAP VOD.hasGaps VOD.Count
2021-04-08 07:30:00    18.95    18.95   18.91     18.92        246  18.921           0        49
2021-04-08 07:31:00    18.91    18.91   18.90     18.90         69  18.905           0        31
2021-04-08 07:32:00    18.90    18.90   18.87     18.87        237  18.881           0        44
2021-04-08 07:33:00    18.87    18.87   18.86     18.87         45  18.870           0        20
2021-04-08 07:34:00    18.87    18.87   18.85     18.86        173  18.860           0        57
2021-04-08 07:35:00    18.86    18.87   18.85     18.86         39  18.859           0        19
```

Comment: I edited the above. I added `endDateTime = "20210408 13:24:28"` and it still shows data from the previous day 2021-04-07.

Comment: It turns out you need realtime subscription to get same day data. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it resolved.  IB's descriptions of its data subscriptions often fall short when trying to figure out what's needed.  By the way, your code is an excellent example for data retrieval.

Comment: btw, any realtime sub works. you can can get the MTF bundle which is cheaper than the primaries.